# Injective and surjective functions in ℕ

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $f:\mathbb N\to \mathbb N$ be an injective function.

Let $g:\mathbb N\to \mathbb N$ be a surjective function

prove that $f(n)≥g(n)$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$.

this exercise has been puzzling me a long time. 
the most reasonable proof would by finding a contradiction, and by proving that surjective functions from $\mathbb N\to \mathbb N$  Would have to either be an identity function or a function that assigns different values to even and odd numbers ( I could be wrong)
I tried playing a bit with the properties of injective and surgective functions since an injective function in N would have to be strictly increasing.
p.s : I'm still a highschooler so I'm fairly ignorant.

Comment: Do you mean $f(x)\ge h(x)?$

Comment: Thanks I made a typo

Comment: I think what you want to prove is false : take $f : n \mapsto n$ ang $h : n \mapsto n-1$ if $n >0$ or $1$ if $n=0$; then $f(0)<h(0).

Comment: I expect you mean to assume that $f$ is increasing...something like that.  Otherwise your claim is false, as others have remarked.

Comment: I think you're probably guaranteed that $f(n)\ge g(n)$ for infinitely many $n$, but not better than that.

Comment: "an injective function in N would have to be strictly increasing". This doesn't hold for functions $f:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}.$ It is true for continous functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ if you include strictly decreasing.

Comment: I believe f is supposed to be strictly injective, so it cannot be bijective

Comment: What do you mean by "strictly injective"? Do you mean "strictly increasing"? In any case, "strictly increasing" and "bijective" are not incompatible.

Answer (score 2):

The claim is false.

Consider $$f(1)=2,f(2)=1,f(n)=n,\forall n\ge 3$$ and $$g(n)=n,\forall n\ge 2.$$

We have that $f$ is injective, $g$ is surjective and $f(2)<g(2)$.

Answer (score 0):

My claim is indeed false, I'll review my old exercises book and double check the execise, sorry for the mistake.